# Fill in range with minimum of row range in vba and proceed with next row

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to figure a way to do the following two conditions in excel vba.

1. Add values in increments of 1 to a row range.
2. Each increment should begin with a skipped cell, the next iteration to begin with the empty cell
3. The starting point for the next row should be the minimum of the column sum from the previous rows

The Below code gives the below output-
[image]

```
Sub main()

Dim need, lines, oldLines As Integer
Dim TS, shift As String
Dim minRange As Range
Dim i, j, k, l As Integer
    lines = 0
    Range("J1").Select
Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
    Select Case TS
          Case ActiveCell.Offset(1, -7).Value = 2
           need = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 8).Value
                      
         Do Until need = 0
           For i = 1 To 7 Step 2
               oldLines = ActiveCell.Offset(1, i).Value
               oldLines = oldLines + 1
               ActiveCell.Offset(1, i).Value = oldLines
                need = need - 1
               If need = 0 Then Exit For
           Next i
           
         Loop
    
    End Select
     ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    
Loop
    
    MsgBox "Done!"
End Sub
```

Can the code be modified to achieve something like below -

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Your goal is very unclear. Even looking at your 2 screenshots I'm unable to tell what you tried to do.

Comment: I am trying to fill in increments of 1 so that they align to the Need column. The end objective is to keep minimum variance at a row-level and the totals for each column. 
In the code, I am trying to add in the values by skipping alternate columns in the first iteration, but in the second iteration, I need to begin by the minimum of that row. So if the need is 9 the first iteration would be 1,,1,,1,,1 then 1,1,1,1,1,1,1 and finally 1,2,1,2,1,1,1